# How to combine multiple spreadsheet into one sheet using ID with Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I just want to ask about how to combine data from multiple spreadsheets into one sheet by using their ID. So, I made 2 sheets in the Master spreadsheet (1 for Data Master and 1 for ID list). I want to take the ID from ID List Sheet to get the file and a sheet that I would like to combine. I have using the DriveApp.getFileById but it's still not working. My current Script is using the file name list to access the data on sheet2 only and still not working. Do you have any solution to change or repair my script? It'll be very helpful. Thank you!

Note: The Source spreadsheets data can always be updated

This is my current Script (Inspired by https://codewithcurt.com/combine-multiple-spreadsheets-into-one-google-sheet/):

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheetIDurl = 'xxxxxxxx';
  
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheetIDurl).getSheetByName('ID').getDataRange().getValues();
  
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxxxxxxxx');
  
  var ssa = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  var copySheet = ssa.getSheetByName('Master');
  copySheet.getRange('A2:Z').clear();
  var search = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < source.length; i++) {
    
    search = source[i][0].toString();

    var file = folder.getFilesByName(search);

    while (file.hasNext()) {
      var getFile = file.next();
      break;
    }
    Logger.log(getFile);
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.open(getFile);
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');

    for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
      var nameSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheets[i].getName());
      var nameRange = nameSheet.getDataRange();
      var nameValues = nameRange.getValues();

      for (var y = 1; y < nameValues.length; y++) {
        copySheet.appendRow(nameValues[y]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Get the ID from ID List as an array and loop through it to get the data from spreadsheet..

Comment: So you have sheet, which contains all the IDs of spreadsheet, and you have to get the data from every spreadsheet, and paste it in separate sheet as consolidated data? and one more thing, from source spreadsheet, from which sheet you want to extract data?

Comment: Yes and from source spreadsheets, I want to extract data from Sheet2

Comment: Added a sample script, please try!

Comment: Okay, I'll try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below Sample Script after changing sheet names :-

```
function data_Merger()
{
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const mergeSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Master Sheet Name, where data should be pasted'); //Change sheet name
  const id_Sheet = ss.getSheetByName('ID SheetName'); //Change sheet name
  const IDs = id_Sheet.getRange('A2:A').getValues().flat() // Change to your column range which contains IDs
  var mergedData = []
  for(var i = 0 ; i < IDs.length ; i++)
  { 
       var ns = SpreadsheetApp.openById(IDs[i]).getSheetByName('Sheet2')
       var MRange = ns.getRange(2, 1, ns.getLastRow()-1, ns.getLastColumn()).getValues()   // Excluding Header Row
       for(var j = 0 ; j < MRange.length ; j++)
       {
         mergedData.push(MRange[j])
       }     
  }
  
  mergeSheet.getRange(2, 1, mergedData.length, mergedData[0].length).setValues(mergedData) // Pasting data in Master Sheet  
}
```

- Structure of all the sheets should be exactly same.

Comment: There is a error on 
var ns = SpreadsheetApp.openById(IDs[i]).getSheetByName('Sheet2'). 
It say: Exception: Invalid argument: id

Comment: Did you change the range which contains IDs  in your ID sheet in this line `id_Sheet.getRange('A2:A').getValues().flat() ` , it should contains, also remove the header cell if you've.

Comment: The range is actually same like my ID sheet

Comment: If you guys want to use this code, please update to this line: const IDs = id_Sheet.getRange('A2:A').getValues().flat().filter(r=>r); 

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is elegant and works fine. The only issue I was facing was "Exception: Invalid argument: url data_Merger"

The issue seems to be the ID.length. When I have 3 links and give it as below, it works fine.
const IDs = id_Sheet.getRange('A1:A3').getValues().flat() // Change to your column range which contains IDs

But if I give it as A1:A, it gives me an error. Logging ID.length gives its value as 997 when it should be 3 and so the counter doesn't stop.

Instead, I made the following changes and it worked well. Replaced ID.length with total_IDs

var total_IDs = id_Sheet.getLastRow();
for(var i = 0 ; i < total_IDs; i++)

Comment: Hello! Sorry for the late reply. I forgot to adjust the final answer. There is some changes that @vector made because the error that I've got.
const IDs = id_Sheet.getRange('A1:A3').getValues().flat().filter(r => r);

Comment: Maybe it is different than your problem, but you can try to change that line. Thank you and I apologize for the late information

Comment: When you change the getRange to "A1:A" and you use the new line, I think it can solve your problem. Because it will search the correct ID and save the filtered ID to the variable IDs. The inside of IDs.length will be only the filtered and not looping till the bottom of the spreadsheet, but looping as many as the filtered data that contained on variable IDs. Hope it can solve your problem. Thank you